# Подключение к Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle

Хочу подключить приложение к Firebase, для этого надо узнать SHA-1. Помню, что можно было воспользоваться градлом слева, но сейчас я терминала не вижу. Как узнать SHA-1?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откройте консоль в AndroidStudio и выполните

```
gradlew signinReport
```